# Bittrex API returns APIKEY_NOT_PROVIDED

Tags: ios, rest, alamofire

I'm trying to call Bittrex api in my sample iOS application.

I got the following message.

**Return Message**

```
SUCCESS: {
    message = "APIKEY_NOT_PROVIDED";
    result = "<null>";
    success = 0;
}
```

And I checked HTTP request, apikey was included as below.

**API Request**

```
$ curl -i \
    -b "__cfduid=dea9a55b977dded0f94ad14f7158f03e91497078592" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "Accept-Language: en;q=1.0" \
    -H "apisign: 41a5b3a98d7da9bee01ddb8ab72dee...." \
    -H "User-Agent: SampleApp/1.0 (com.sampleapp.SampleApp; build:1; iOS 10.3.1) Alamofire/4.4.0" \
    -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip;q=1.0, compress;q=0.5" \
    -d "{\"apikey\":\"f23439b...\",\"nonce\":\"1497703898.0\"}" \
"https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/account/getbalances"
```

And my code is like following.

**Code**

```
let timeInterval = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
let epochtime = String(floor(timeInterval))
let parameters = "apikey=" + "f23439b..." + "&" + "nonce=" + epochtime
let url = path + "getbalances" + "?" + parameters
let secretKey: String = "df8a62...".hmac(algorithm: CryptoAlgorithm.SHA512, key: url)

Alamofire.request(path + "getbalances", 
                  method: .get, 
                  parameters: ["apikey":"f23439b...", "nonce":epochtime], 
                  encoding: JSONEncoding.default, 
                  headers: ["apisign":secretKey])
    .responseJSON(completionHandler: { response in
        let json = response.result.value as! NSDictionary
        let success = json["success"] as! CFBoolean
        if (success == kCFBooleanTrue) {
            //do something
            print(json)
        } else {
            let reason = response.result.description as AnyObject
            print(reason)
        }
    })
```

**Environment**

- macOS Sierra
- XCode 8.3.3
- Swift 3
- Alamofire 4.4

Comment: and your HTTP request (which you're doing on the command line) works fine?  Or does it fail with both `curl` and within the app?

Comment: HTTP request returns HTTP STATUS 200 OK with both curl and within the app.

Comment: The question I was trying to get answered was:  does the `curl` command actually work, or does the `SUCCESS` response also show a `APIKEY_NOT_PROVIDED` message?

Comment: Yes, it returns `APIKEY_NOT_PROVIDED`, too. I figure out the problem is at `Almofire.request`. When I execute curl command manually without '-d' option such as `curl -i "https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/account/getbalances?apikey=f23439..." -H "apisign:467d5..."`, I could get correct result. But  Almofire generates parameters with '-d' option instead of '?param=value&...`.

Comment: I finally figure out my wrong code. The correct code was `let secretKey: String = url.hmac(algorithm: CryptoAlgorithm.SHA512, key: "df8a62")`. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: try - https://github.com/yuzushioh/BittrexKit

Answer (score 6):

I believe you have a problem with the new V1.1 API, where you need to encrypt Secret with HMAC-SHA512:

> For this version, we use a standard HMAC-SHA512 signing. Append `apikey` and `nonce` to your request and calculate the HMAC hash and include it under an `apisign` header. Note: the nonce is not respected right now but will be enforced later.

Not iOS expert, but this might help you out:

```
$apikey='xxx';
$apisecret='xxx';
$nonce=time();
$uri='https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/market/getopenorders?apikey='.$apikey.'&nonce='.$nonce;
$sign=hash_hmac('sha512',$uri,$apisecret);
$ch = curl_init($uri);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('apisign:'.$sign));
$execResult = curl_exec($ch);
$obj = json_decode($execResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like a simple typo / you should be using api secret and the string presupposing I believe should be the uri(not url).  There's a swift BittrexKit library that's using Crypro library - with a slightly different method signature.

```
let secretKey: String = URI.hmac(algorithm: CryptoAlgorithm.SHA512, key: APISECRET)
```

cherry picked from 
https://github.com/yuzushioh/BittrexKit

```
import Crypto

    guard let sign = HMAC.sign(message: uri, algorithm: .sha512, key: auth.apiSecret) else {
        print("Bittrex: HMAC failed")
    }



  private func buildURI() -> String? {
    let url = path.isEmpty ? baseURL : baseURL.appendingPathComponent(path)

    guard var components = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true) else {
        return nil
    }

    if let queryParameters = queryParameters, !queryParameters.isEmpty {
        components.percentEncodedQuery = URLEncodedSerialization.string(from: queryParameters)
    }

    guard let uri = components.url?.absoluteString else {
        return nil
    }

    return uri
  }
```

(if someone gets this working with alamofire - I welcome any edits.)